# What are the time complexities of finding kth element from beginning and kth element from end in a doubly linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists

What are the time complexities of finding kth element from beginning and kth element from end in a doubly linked list? Assume n > k, where k is a constant and n is a total number of nodes in the linked list.

O(1) and O(n)

O(1) and O(1)

O(n) and O(1)

O(n) and O(n)

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, **k** can vary from **1 to n.**

### 1

> We might be interested in finding 1<sup>st</sup> from Beginning and 1<sup>st</sup> from End.

> Time Complexities of these are respectively $O(1)$ and $O(n)$.

### OR

### n

> We might be interested in finding n<sup>th</sup> Element from Beginning (Last Element of Linked List) and n<sup>th</sup> Element from End (First Element of Linked List)

> Time Complexities of these are respectively $O(n)$ and $O(1)$.

Since, we are not sure of what **k** is, we will **try to find** the **Average Case**

Now, Average Time Complexity can be calculated as Sum of Time Complexities Of All Cases divided by Total number of Cases.

### Now, **finding k<sup>th</sup> element from beginning**

$$T=\frac{1+2+3+.......+(n-2)+(n-1)+n}{n}$$

Using formula,
$$T=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n}$$

Simplifying
$$T=\frac{n+1}{2}$$

Thus,
$$T=O(n)$$

### Now, **finding k<sup>th</sup> element from end**

$$T=\frac{n+(n-1)+(n-2)+.......+3+2+1}{n}$$

Using formula,
$$T=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n}$$

Simplifying
$$T=\frac{n+1}{2}$$

Thus,
$$T=O(n)$$

Thus, **Average Case Time Complexities** in both cases will be $O(n)$